# SourceTree gives me a login Error when I try to add my gitlab account

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I would like to add my gitlab account to sourcetree.  Inside Preferences -> Accounts, I tried the 'add' button

```
host: GitLab.com
Auth type: greyed out
username xxxxxx
password: xxxxxx
protocol: https
```

when I go to save.  I get a pop up screen that says: "We couldn't connect to GitLab with your (XXXXXX) credentials. Check your username and try the password again."

I've double checked both username and password.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Someone on the GitLab forum had a [similar issue](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/configure-sourcetree/600/24) recently, and they documented the steps to solve it:

> I eventually noticed that for github and bitbucket the credentials are through "Oauth", and for GitLab "Personal access token". I had generated yesterday a toke, but hadn't used anywhere.
>
> Steps to add a repo from GitLab on SourceTree:
>
> 1. On your browser, go to your account and > User settings > Personal Access Tokens (https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens)
> 2. Generate and copy the token
> 3. On Sourcetree,
>
>    a) leave https as preferred protocol
>
>    b) click on Refresh Personal Access Token
>
>    c) type your username
>
>    d) use the **copied token** as **password**

Refer below image
[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I don't see an option for Refresh Personal Access token.  I only have a link for "How do I create a private token"

Comment: Which SourceTree version are you using?

Comment: Version 3. For Mac

Comment: And there is no way to reenter the password there?

Comment: I figured it out.  I didn't read carefully.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: [SourceTree docs for "creating-a-personal-access-token"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#creating-a-personal-access-token).

Comment: Heads up: instead of "refresh token", just add a new user to your source tree users section and use the "Personal Access Token" created on the Gitlab website as a password

Comment: I remember this solution. Now I'm having a different problem and I just gave up, and used Terminal instead. For some reason, my GitLab account was removed from Sourcetree, and after doing this solution, I now can't push or pull using Sourcetree, it says authentication failed. Wow, GitLab has always been this pain in the backside. :/

Comment: All thanx to @marcelosalloum who find out that personal access token should be used  instead of passwrd.

Comment: Where is Refresh Personal Access Token @DavidPlanella? you said click on it

Comment: Same here, just installed Sourcetree latest version today and there is no 'Refresh Personal Access Token' link, neither there is source tree 'users' section, so none of the above solution working for me. Anyone figured this out?

Comment: For some reason "Refresh Personal Access Token" field is not in the latest update in Sourcetree. However, if you write your Personal Access Token in the password field, it will let you connect to your account. @VC2019

Answer (score 4):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

**The solution was (on Mac):**

- revoke the old Access Token from GitLab (which had only the next Scopes: read_repository, write_repository)
- generate new Access Token having the next Scopes: api, read_user, read_repository, write_repository (it was strange that for other colleague it worked only with read_repository, write_repository)
- on SourceTree: go to SourceTree -> Preferences ->Accounts -> Add -> fill-in the details as in the following image (and for Password use the Access Token):

[image]

After this, I was able to Clone Repository ("Clone from URL").

Also, this link inspired me: https://www.awordfromnet.com/access-gitlab-via-sourcetree-updated/

Comment: Solved for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me but i solved it by

- Replacing the Host by : gitlab.com
- username : your gitlab username
- password : your personnal access_token availiable on gitlab more on this link : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#creating-a-personal-access-token

Answer (score 3):

I am adding some advantage to @David's answer. Follow whatever steps he has mentioned but remember to select all scopes while creating a personal token.